# Failed to view image while converting from numpy array

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-learn

Actually, I have 2d list(5,20000). First, I converted the list into numpy array.

```
a = np.array(my_2_dlist)
```

[image]

then I normalized the array from 0 to 255 and made all the values to integer. Afterwards, I used python-opencv to write the image.

```
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 255))
scaled_x = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(a).astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imwrite('filename.jpeg', scaled_x)
```

It seems to me, I got perfect result for scaled_x, all the values are between 0 to 255 with no negetive numbers. The image was also saved perfectly in my folder.
[image]
But when I opened the image I see nothing. I am perplexed; why I am not seeing anything, the very same code is working for other code samples.

[image]

Comment: Does your image have dimension fornat and so on

Comment: Check if cv2.imwrite needs to be told to save a grayscale image

Comment: @pippo1980 no on both suggestions. those are not the issue.

Comment: your code works with me, maybe there is something wron with the list, provide a sample of it

Comment: it's likely that there is a very negative value in your data. simply minmax-scaling is sometimes a bad idea. you need to apply *assumptions* about the range of values you have there.

Answer (score 0):

`imwrite` needs to be given uint8 data if the values are 0 to 255.

If the values are float, they must be ranged 0.0 to 1.0.

Comment: scaled_x = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(a).astype(np.uint8)